# Definition of global weak solution to PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

What is the definition of a global weak solution to a parabolic PDE?

Is it a solution $u \in L^2_{loc}(0,\infty;V)$ with $u' \in L^2_{loc}(0,T;V')$ or is it a solution $u \in L^2(0,\infty;V)$ with $u' \in L^2(0,T;V')$ ?

If the latter, how is the weak derivative defined on the interval $(0,\infty)?$

Comment: I think @aere that both definitions are acceptable, it depends on the context. Also when you define weak derivative, you only integrate against functions with compact support, so both definitions make sense.

Comment: @Tomás So one should use test functions $\varphi \in C_c^\infty(0,T)$ for every $T > 0$ is what you mean I suppose.

Comment: You can use $\varphi\in  C_c^\infty (0,\infty)$. What is the problem?

Comment: Oh I see. I didn't think of that..